# Generic plugin develop for eclipse IDE and intellij IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, intellij-plugin

I have develop plugin for eclipse IDE and also same plugin develop for IntelliJ IDEA. Is there any way how to develop plugin working for both eclipse IDE and intelliJ IDEA. i want to allows to access the existing projects in the workspace, create new projects and modify and read existing projects. Is there better way like Java parse or  Abstract Syntax Tree. can i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The plugin API of Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA is completely different; you'll need to develop two separate plugins.

Comment: Can i use AST or parsing for allows to access the existing project in work space or modify existing projects?

Comment: You can, but the abstract syntax tree API is also completely different between Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA (where it's called PSI).